# How to set the all items size according to the largest item in the layout in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview with gridlayout, getting some of the items with large height of the content. I want to set the same height of all items that will be equal to the largest item height or the equal height of the horizontal items without changing the layout.

XML -->

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvSubTitle"
    style="@style/darkMedium"
    android:text="Fabulous Foot "
    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_regular"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgExperience"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle">
</TextView>
```

Its parent layout is constraint and there is one more textView below it.

It is looking like this.

[image: It is looking like this.]

[![It should be look like this][2]][2]

Want to make it like this.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7eE0.png

Comment: post some related code (XML, adaper, initing lines), no one will write entire solution for you, when you already have probably most of needed code

Answer (score 0):

could you share your layout.xml file or UI/UX design here? I can just suggest you  now without much information that you should design layout with maximum height and width of each view. Use SDP and SSP library to support multiple resolution and devices.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. Some humble suggestions: Please use comments section under the question when you are asking for more details of the problem OP is facing. It is better to post answer after you have enough information. Also when you suggest to use some library or component it would be great if you could also tell (or point to some link that tells) how to add that library to the project.

Comment: I have posted please check it out.